# Inverting an obviously untrue hypothesis does not prove falsehood

Tags: coq, inversion

I am trying to prove a trivial lemma, which is a recreation of a situation I found myself in at another point.

```coq
Lemma Sn_neq_n: forall n, S n <> n.
```

The proof seems as simple as it gets:

```coq
Proof. unfold not. intros.
```

Now my goal state shows:

```coq
n : nat
H : S n = n
===================
 False
```

Well it is obvious that `S n` can't be unified with `n`, so I should be able to just invert this hypothesis:

```coq
inversion H.
```

But instead of solving the goal, my state now shows:

```coq
n : nat
H : S n = n
H0 : S n = n
===================
 False
```

Huh? I'm just in an infinite loop now. I can `inversion H0` and I just get an `H1`, etc.

I was able to prove the lemma by induction:

```coq
unfold not. intros. induction n.
Case "n = 0". inversion H.
Case "n > 0". inversion H. apply IHn. apply H1.
```

But that's a bit silly, because conceivably the unification algorithm, which allows reflexive equality to make sense in the first place, should not be able to unify `S n` with `n`.

What's going on here ?

Comment: The `inversion` tactic either performs case analysis on a predicate or simplifies an equation between constructors. It doesn't apply to your hypothesis. Also, unification is probably stronger than Coq's logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see why `inversion` isn't able to solve this goal on its own, we need to understand what it is doing in more detail.

When you invert a hypothesis of (co)inductive type, what Coq does, roughly speaking, is to extract as much information as it can from it *using only pattern matching* (remember that Coq tactics are always producing proof terms under the hood). Thus, when proving `1 <> 0` by inversion, Coq will produce a term that looks like this:

```coq
Definition one_neq_zero (p : 1 = 0) : False :=
  match p in _ = n return match n with
                          | 0 => False
                          | _ => True
                          end
  with
  | eq_refl => I (* "I" is the only constructor of the True proposition *)
  end.
```

The `return` annotation on the `match` statement is crucial for this to work. What is happening here is essentially the following:

- We need to match on the equality proof `p` to use it.
- In order to be able to talk about the right-hand side of that equation when pattern-matching on its proof, we must add a return annotation to our match.
- Unfortunately, this return annotation can't mention 0 directly. Instead, it needs to work for a *generic* `n`, *even though we know that that element is actually 0*. This is just because of the way pattern matching works in Coq.
- On the return annotation, we play a "trick" on Coq: we say that we will return `False` on the case that we actually care about (i.e., `n = 0`), but say that we'll return something else on the other branches.
- To type-check the `match`, each branch must return something of the type that appears on the `return` clause, but after substituting the *actual values* of the variables that were bound on the `in` clause.
- In our case, there is only one constructor for the equality type, `eq_refl`. Here, we know that `n = 1`. Substituting 1 for `n` in our return type, we obtain `True`, so we must return something of type `True`, which we do.
- Finally, since the right-hand side of `p` is 0, Coq understands that the type of the whole match is `False`, so the whole definition type-checks.

The last step only works because 0 is a constructor, so Coq is able to simplify the match on the return type to realize that we are returning the right thing. *This* is what fails when trying to invert `S n = n`: since `n` is a variable, the entire match can't be simplified.

We could try to flip the equality and invert `n = S n` instead, so that Coq would be able to simplify the return type a little bit. Unfortunately, this wouldn't work either, and for a similar reason. For instance, if you tried to annotate the match with `in _ = m return match m with 0 => True | _ => False end`, inside the `eq_refl` we would have to return something of type `match n with 0 => True | _ => False end`, which we can't.

Finally I should mention that the unification algorithm inside Coq cannot be used "negatively" like you alluded to, because the theory only defines the things that are *provable*, and not which things are *refutable*. In particular, when we prove a negated proposition such as `S n <> n`, the type checker is always testing whether certain unification problems have a solution, as opposed to testing whether they have *no* solution. For instance, assuming that `n = m` is a perfectly fine thing to do, and doesn't result in any contradictions, even though `n` and `m` are *not* unifiable. Also notice that, if `nat` were declared as a *co-inductive* type instead, `S n = n` is *not* a contradictory hypothesis, and the difference between the two is just that on this case we wouldn't be able to do induction on `n`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the more elaborate `match` statement syntax; to this point I've only written `match a with | c => d | e => f end`, so it's a little hard for me to follow. But I definitely appreciate the writeup and will return to this when I've seen and used the "full" version of `match`!

Comment: The generic form of the `match` statement, where the return type depends on what's being analyzed, is indeed a bit harder to grasp. You can try to understand what's going on by printing out proof terms directly and seeing what tactics are actually doing (try typing `Print foo.` at the toplevel, where `foo` is the name of a lemma). `inversion` produces a lot of `match`es like this, usually. The tl;dr version of the above would be: `inversion` produces terms only with pattern-matching, and this is not powerful enough to express what you want.